# mysql, insert with select sub query

Tags: mysql

I have lots of products in a `product_category` table with a `category_id` of 5.
I have added a new `category_id` of 19.
How do I add all products in category 5 to category 19 as well?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
insert into product_categories( category_id, product_id )
select 19,
   (select product_id
    from product_categories
    where category_id = 5)
```

but I am getting a `sub query returns more than 1 row` error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO product_categories (category_id, product_id)
  SELECT 19 AS category_id, product_id 
  FROM product_categories 
  WHERE category_id =5;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (field, field, timestamp) 
 VALUES (
     (SELECT id FROM tablex WHERE id = :xid LIMIT 1),
     (SELECT id FROM tabley WHERE id = :yid LIMIT 1),
     NOW()
 )
```

Comment: you shouldn't really need the LIMIT's - but handy if you're not using unique row id's

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO product_categories( category_id, product_id )
SELECT 19, product_id FROM product_categories WHERE category_id =5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with limit

```
INSERT INTO product_categories( category_id, product_id ) SELECT 19 , (

SELECT product_id FROM product_categories WHERE category_id =5 LIMIT 1)
```